# Syntax error while saving postgresql server info in setting.py Django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am getting Syntax error while saving postgresql server information in setting.py file of Django and running server. Below are the settings i am saving in setting.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'webportal',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'password'
        'HOST':'localhost',
        'PORT' : '5432',
    }
}
```

and the error is :-

```
\Django_Project\project2\WebPortal-Project>manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AJ!!\Dropbox\Django_Project\project2\WebPortal-Project\manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\AJ!!\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\AJ!!\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 317, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "C:\Users\AJ!!\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\AJ!!\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Users\AJ!!\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 106, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Users\AJ!!\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 674, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 781, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 741, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\AJ!!\Dropbox\Django_Project\project2\WebPortal-Project\WebPortal\settings.py", line 83
    'HOST':'localhost',
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Could you please help me figure out what is this syntax error appears.

Comment: You forgot a comma after the `'PASSWORD'` line, so Python "mixes" `'password'` and `'HOST'`.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a comma after the `'PASSWORD': 'password'` line.